# What is _mh_execute_header?

Tags: ios, xcode, bugsense

I'm getting '_mh_execute_header' as error position from production ios app (I'm using BugSense): I'd like to know what is it and what it means.

During development we use testflight  to release beta version to our testers and among team components: during tests we didn't get such error position.

I manage development and release to the store is done by another team member: can this situation happens due to some different settings in xcode IDE between me and the releaser?

Thanks!

Comment: somehow you managed to get it?

Comment: not yet :( ...maybe it's due to symbolication....

Answer (score 9):

This might help you : [In iOS, what caused this crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871433/in-ios-what-caused-this-crash) (specifically, the answer stating that using [CrashKit](https://github.com/kaler/CrashKit) could be advantageous.) Also have a look at [iOS App: Several crashes with common themes of: SIGSEGV and _sigtramp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462505/ios-app-several-crashes-with-common-themes-of-sigsegv-and-sigtramp)

> "_mh_execute_header is a known symbol/address that it uses as a base
>   to calculate an offset when it has no better information."
>   – Phillip Mills Nov 20 '12 at 14:08

Also, see this link for a discussion on a similar thing happening to somebody else : http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2012/Sep/msg00316.html