# In iOS, what caused this crash?

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports

I got a crash in my iOS app, but their has only a few messages, some like this.

```
Application received signal SIGABRT
(null)
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x359c68a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x37d6d259 objc_exception_throw + 32
2   CoreFoundation                      0x359c6789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x359c67ab +[NSException raise:format:] + 34
4   myapp                               0x00241bf9 _ZNSt11_Deque_baseIsSaIsEE15_M_create_nodesEPPsS3_ + 1432772
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32dd27e3 _sigtramp + 38
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32dc820f pthread_kill + 54
7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32dc129f abort + 94
8   libc++abi.dylib                     0x35d7ef6b abort_message + 46
9   libc++abi.dylib                     0x35d7c3f1 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 120
10  libc++abi.dylib                     0x35d7c451 _ZdlPv + 0
11  libc++abi.dylib                     0x35d7d825 __cxa_current_exception_type + 0
12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x37d6d2a9 objc_exception_rethrow + 12
13  CoreFoundation                      0x3591c50d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
14  CoreFoundation                      0x3591c36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
15  GraphicsServices                    0x375b8439 GSEventRunModal + 136
16  UIKit                               0x33428cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
17  myapp                               0x000d4293 _mh_execute_header + 41619
18  myapp                               0x000ccd20 _mh_execute_header + 11552
)
```

I can't find what caused this crash, but it is the most frequently appears in my app. I am very anxious, does any one know something about it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected/13576028#13576028

Comment: I guess you can't reproduce locally with an exception breakpoint. As it is is impossible to solve if you don't symbolicate the stack trace (= find out what method is at _mh_execute_header + 41619, etc.).

Comment: Looks like the crash report is generated on an armv7s device and whatever created the crash report isn't handling that chip correctly which results in bad symbols when symbolicating. All those symbols for your app are completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to reproduce this crash either by performing a certain task or just using the app long enough you could attach the debugger and set a breakpoint for `[NSException raise]`. This way you can figure out in what part of your application stuff is messed up, I used this in the past to figure out where a NSArray went out of bounds.. ( and I have like a dozen or more spread around all source files )

Secondly you should probably 'symbolicate' the crash report so you can follow the stack trace.. so you can figure out what method/class in your code is messing stuff up.

Answer (score 1):

For see a crash callback, try add in your project this great feature:

[CrashKit](https://github.com/kaler/CrashKit)

This is a exception catcher