# ios crash _mh_execute_header (any idea ?)

Tags: ios, crash

I need help please.

So, I made an app, during the development, nothing wrong, all my beta custommer got no error. 
But now I have a lot of crash taht I can't reproduce myself.
I don't know how to do it and when it appening .
I got the crash report with crashlytics.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Exception Type: SIGABRT Code: ABORT at 0x1013650256

```
com.apple.main-thread Crashed
 libsystem_kernel.dylib  __pthread_kill + 8
 libsystem_c.dylib   pthread_kill + 58
 libsystem_c.dylib   abort + 94
 XXXXX2      _mh_execute_header + 6703
 UIKit   -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 784
 UIKit   -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2458
 UIKit   -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
 UIKit   _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6154
 GraphicsServices    _PurpleEventCallback + 590
 GraphicsServices    PurpleEventCallback + 34
 CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
 CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 138
 CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1384
 CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
 CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
 GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 74
 UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1120
 XXXXX2 
main.m line 17
main
com.apple.libdispatch-manager
 ...     libsystem_kernel.dylib  kevent64 + 24
     libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 796
     libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 35
WebThread
 ...     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_trap + 20
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg + 40
     CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 128
     CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 882
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
     WebCore     RunWebThread(void*) + 444
     libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 308

com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
 ...     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_trap + 20
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg + 40
     CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 128
     CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 882
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
     Foundation  +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 308
     Foundation  __NSThread__main__ + 972
     libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 308
com.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_trap + 20
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg + 40
     XXXXX2  CLSMachExceptionServer
     libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 308

com.apple.CFSocket.private
 libsystem_kernel.dylib  __select + 20
 libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 308

JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
 libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait + 24
 libsystem_c.dylib   pthread_cond_timedwait + 44
 JavaScriptCore  WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 108
 JavaScriptCore  JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 82
 JavaScriptCore  WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 14
 libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 308

JavaScriptCore::Marking
 libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait + 24
 libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_cond_wait + 646
 libsystem_c.dylib   pthread_cond_wait + 40
 JavaScriptCore  JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 148
 JavaScriptCore  JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 144
 JavaScriptCore  WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 14
 libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 308

Thread 8
 libsystem_kernel.dylib  __workq_kernreturn + 8
 libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_workq_return + 18
 libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_wqthread + 365

Thread 9
 libsystem_kernel.dylib  __workq_kernreturn + 8
 libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_workq_return + 18
 libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_wqthread + 365
```

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462505/ios-app-several-crashes-with-common-themes-of-sigsegv-and-sigtramp... it might help... oh and there is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654235/what-is-mh-execute-header

Comment: I already saw it but I can't find where I'm wrong
Thanks
Do you know if the error freeze the apps or if it's a background error  and nothing happend to the customer ?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are doing networking blocking calls on the main thread?  This causes watchdog timeouts, but I couldn't following your stack back trace properly (it has been pruned).